# How to construct object using C# - CodeDOM

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I have method that assign value to property and generate code statement using C# CodeDOM.

```
private static CodeAssignStatement setProp(string propName, object propValue, Type propType, Type objType)
{
                CodeAssignStatement declareVariableName = null;
                if (propType.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    declareVariableName = new CodeAssignStatement(
                   new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("testObj"), propName), new CodePrimitiveExpression(propValue)
                   );
                }
                else
                {
                    declareVariableName = new CodeAssignStatement(
                    new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("testObj"), propName),
                     new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("\"" + propValue?.ToString() + "\"")
                    );
                }

                return declareVariableName;
}
```

For primitive value it is generating statements correctly. However, for rest, e.g. DateTime it generates statement like `testObj.PurchasedOn = "17-09-2016 18:50:00";`. One way to use target data type "Parse" methods. But it may not be available for other data types. How can I construct object? Is there any method available in framework?

Comment: I don't think there is a general way to do this, since every type can be constructed in a different way (and some don't even have public way to construct them).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that you are attempting to assign a value to a variable where the variable is an object data type.

```
int i = 123; // This is fine as it assigns the primitive value 123 to the integer variable i.
string s = "123"; // This is also fine as you're assigning the string value "123" to the string variable s.
string t = s; // This is fine as long as variable s is a string datatype.
```

Your code is attempting to assign a value to an object datatype.

```
testObj.PurchasedOn = "17-09-2016 18:50:00"; // This won't work as you cannot assign a string constant to a DateTime variable.
```

As you mention, you could use the `Parse` method if it is available.

If we look at the code you are expecting to produce it would most likely look like this:

```
testObj.PurchasedOn = new DateTime(2016, 09, 17, 18, 50, 0);
```

As you can see, for the `DateTime` object constructor you would need to specify 6 parameters. This will obviously vary for every object type you wish to create.

The solution lies in the `CodeObjectCreateExpression` class which can be used in place of the `CodePrimitiveExpression` class.

I would suggest changing your method to accept a `CodeExpression` rather than `object propValue`. That way you can provide a primitive or an object instantiator.

In this case you could pass to your method:

```
new CodeObjectCreateExpression(typeof(DateTime), 2016, 09, 17, 18, 50, 0);
```

You can find more details on [`CodeObjectCreateExpression` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeobjectcreateexpression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

What if you just get rid of your conditional and do:

```
private static CodeAssignStatement setProp(string propName, object propValue, Type propType, Type objType)
{
    CodeAssignStatement declareVariableName = null;
    declareVariableName = new CodeAssignStatement(
        new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("testObj"), propName),
        new CodePrimitiveExpression(propValue)
    );

    return declareVariableName;
}
```

CodePrimitiveExpression appears to take in an [object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx), which means you can assign pretty much anything to it. As such, if you pass in a DateTime, it will be correctly stored as such.

Comment: As name suggests, method is for primitive types only. For your code, it gives exception -``Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Invalid Primitive Type: System.DateTime. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.``

Comment: Posted the answer only because it's working fine on my end. Using Mono 4.6 on OS X.